# C# Interfaces, Polymorphism and Delegates

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates, polymorphism

I have a mess when I combine interfaces and polymorphism.

Say I have the following interface:

```
public Interface CanSayHello
{
     String SayHello();
}
```

The following class:

```
public Class Person : CanSayHello
{
     public String SayHello() { return "Hey, I'm a person just saying hello to you";}
}
```

And finally the important Class:

```
public Class PoshPerson: Person
{
     public String SayHello() { return "Hey, I'm too posh to say hello to you";}
}
```

My first question is would the following code collect the method of PoshClass or Person Class?

```
public delegate String Collector();
event Collector CollectorEvent;
void GetMethod(CanSayHello c){CollectorEvent += c.SayHello;}

**GetMethod(new PoshPerson());**
```

If it will collect the method from Person class, I guess that I should declare the method at Person as virtual and the method at PoshPerson override.
I would really like  that the two method signatures were equal. Is it possible in any way?

Comment: Which of those would you want to happen? If you want the implementation in `PoshPerson` to be called, why would you want to avoid making the methods `virtual` / `override`? Personally, I'd avoid method hiding whenever possible, precisely because compile-time polymorphism is not very intuitive.

Comment: Btw, the coding guidelines say that you should indicate interfaces by putting an I as first letter.

Comment: Should be fairly easy to find out what happens?

Comment: Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example runs `Person`'s method.  If you change `PoshPerson` to `PoshPerson : Person, CanSayHello` (which you might think would change nothing, since `Person : CanSayHello`), it runs `PoshPerson`'s method.

I agree with @millimoose: "I'd avoid method hiding whenever possible, precisely because compile-time polymorphism is not very intuitive."  I would recommend that you change `Person.SayHello` to `virtual`, and `PoshPerson.SayHello` to `override`.  That way regardless of whether you know of the instance as a `CanSayHello`, `Person`, or `PoshPerson`, the current instance type's method runs.

Comment: Also, the compiler will emit a warning to use the `new` keyword in the method declaration in `PoshPerson` if the hiding is in fact intentional.

Answer (score 1):

You example will run Person's version. See the explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664593(v=vs.71).aspx. If you redefine the method in a derived class (the compiled treats PoshPerson.SayHello as if you had used new to redefine it), and the base class implements an interface, the redefined method doesn't alter the interface mapping.

If you have PoshPerson re-implement the interface, it will call PoshPerson's SayHello.

```
public class PoshPerson : Person, CanSayHello
{
    public String SayHello() { return "Hey, I'm too posh to say hello to you";}
}
```

Or if you  make SayHello virtual in Person, and then override it in PoshPerson, it will call PoshPerson's SayHello.

Comment: "If you have PoshPerson explicitly implement the interface" that's a bit misleading, since you're not talking about "explicit interface implementation", but about reimplementing the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more along the lines of:

```
public interface ITalkable
{ 
     string SayHello(); 
     string SayGoodbye();
     etc...
}

public class Person : ITalkable
{ 
     public virtual string SayHello() { return "Hey, I'm a person just saying hello to you";} 
     public virtual string SayGoodbye() { return "Hey, I'm a person just saying goodbye to you";}
} 

public class PoshPerson: Person 
{ 
     public override string SayHello() { return "Hey, I'm too posh to say hello to you";}
     public string MakePersonSayHello() { return base.SayHello(); } 

}
```